# Do sub-queries hit database multiple times if using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

Might seem like a silly question but please read it... I am writing some services and there comes a situation where I have to use sub-query with Entity Framework. Now I have written a query with sub-query but the way I have written it, got me thinking that whether my query is hitting database two times?

Below is the pseudo code of actual query....

```
var data = databaseContext.FirstTable
                          .Where(x => x.Group_Id == (databaseContext.SecondTable
                                                                    .Where(y => y.DomainName == "gmail.com")
                                                                    .Select(x => x.Group_Id)
                                                                    .FirstAndDefault()))
                         .ToList();
```

This query is giving my expected result but I think is hitting the database twice. Am I correct ?

Now I don't want a yes no answer but a short description and can I turn this query into a join one. And some tools or tips to check database hits in SQL Server like a tracer or something.

Comment: Use profiler in ssms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. When you call first or default the Iqueryable will be send to the database. You can trick it by using transactions. Also it's recommended for what you are doing here to use transactions. Also for what you are trying to do i recommend using transitional properties of EF.

```
var data = databaseContext.FirstTable
                          .Include(x=>x.SecondTable)
                          .Where(x => x.SecondTable.DomainName == "gmail.com")
```

The SQL server profiler will show you all queries on the database. Not recommended to use it on anything else than local host of course.